# Oracle Search in stored procedure

Tags: oracle

I want to create a stored procedure that executes an Oracle Search.
The oracle search I want to execute is:

```
SELECT ID, score(1)  from TABLE
WHERE  CONTAINS(column, 'fuzzy(%Item_to_be_searched%)', 1) > 0
order by score(1) DESC;
```

The stored procedure has a parameter `Item_to_be_searched` and should return the `ID` & `Score`.

When I try to create the procedure, there is an error:

> PLS-00222: no function with name 'SCORE' exists in this scope PL/SQL:
>   ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Does anyone know if score can be used in a stored procedure ?

Comment: It considers score(1) as a function. why are you using score(1) instead of score ?

Comment: It was a label that I used but if only 1 contains clause is used, it is redundant.
I tried without (1) and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: The SCORE function may be used in any of these clauses: SELECT, ORDER BY, or GROUP BY.

The value specified for LABEL is the same value defined by the LABEL argument in the CONTAINS function that generated the scores and is referenced by the SCORE function in all other clauses.

If only one CONTAINS function is used in a SELECT statement, the LABEL parameter is not required in the CONTAINS clause, but a SCORE label value of zero (0) will be generated. All other clauses must then refer to SCORE(0) or SCORE(*).